# How to deploy a Haskell web app to Heroku in a simple way?

Tags: haskell, heroku

I've been googling for a while but haven't found an answer to my question. What's a simple way to deploy a haskell application, in particular Snap and Scotty, to heroku? 
I'm looking for a lightweight solution.

Comment: I just googled for `scotty heroku` and found [this](https://github.com/egonSchiele/scotty-heroku) - isn't this what you are looking for?

Comment: [this one](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-15-making-a-website-with-haskell.html) (second entry in the search) is older but should still work

Comment: this question here was the 3rd entry while the 4th yielded another [website](https://haskellonheroku.com/tutorial/) explaining it (not with scotty though - but the way to use the env. variables is present in the short git repo from the first comment)

Comment: @Carsten, none of them worked for me. Why do you give advice if you haven't tried?

Comment: are you kidding me? You did not show any effort nor any code and I should try to magically check 3rd party blog posts against your project? For your information I played with the second one and while it might be outdated in some parts it worked for me - of course you probably have to look into some issues yourself - if you cannot get it working come back and give the errors you get with what **you** tried (code included)